# How do I update the panel launcher icon?

Tags: icons, panel, zorin, launcher

I have a .desktop file in a launcher on the panel.  I want to be able to update the icon used for it from a script.

I run Zorin OS 15.3 education lite (sorry about the Zorin specific terms)

My panel is xfce4-panel 4.14.3

Any help is welcome!

Comment: As answered on Zorin forums: forum.zorin.com/t/how-do-i-update-the-panel-launcher-icon/2889 `xfce4-panel -r` updates the panel. This works beautifully. Thanks to Aravisian for their help on Zorin forums´

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know for launchers on the xfce4-panel you can't add a custom icon. If the application does have an icon then the launcher will show an icon.

Comment: Right.  I can’t claim I understand that, but if you want more information, I’ve more or less brought: this over to Zorin forums: https://forum.zorin.com/t/how-do-i-update-the-panel-launcher-icon/2889.  Thanks, though!